# Source code compatible with the v3.6 of BCGTAD?

Tags: android, commonsware

I have just started learning Android app development and found the "Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development" to be ideal for me.

I am reading the v3.6 of the book. But I could not find a compatible source code for the book hosted on the github repo mentioned on the site.

Is the code hosted elsewhere? Can anyone share the source code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find source code for legacy editions (3.7 and earlier) [at the `cw-android` GitHub repo](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android).